# How to restore MBR (or whatever the issue) so windows 7 can boot?

Tags: windows-7, boot, system-repair-disc

I was going to install Ubuntu 14.04, so I tried creating two partitions from Windows 7. (I'm new to this partitioning thing.)
Initially I had(rounded) C: 150 GB, D: 150 GB, E: 175 GB, 25 GB unallocated

I did this:
Right click on unallocated storage (25 GB) -> New Simple Volume... -> Simple volume size in MB (2048 for swap and rest for root) -> Do not assign a drive letter -> Do not format this volume -> Finish

Now I cannot boot into Windows, It only shows a black screen and a cursor.

I booted up Ubuntu installer through pen drive

It shows(rounded)

```
Device          Type        Size        Used        System
/dev/sda
    /dev/sda1               1 MB        unknown     Windows7(loader)        (must be the MBR, I guess)
    /dev/sda2   ntfs        104 MB      0 MB
    /dev/sda3   ntfs        150 GB      94 MB
    /dev/sda4   ntfs        340 GB      2517 MB                             (as if two drives are joined together.)
```

What do I do? I need to recover the Windows, its settings and all the programs installed.

My computer doesn't have CD drive, I can only use USB flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

boot off a windows 7 usb installation flash drive, and run startup recovery, and you can also try going to the command prompt from the installation usb, and run things like

> bootrec /FixBoot
>
> bootrec /ScanOs
>
> bootrec /RebuildBcd
>
> bootrec /FixMbr

those are windows 7's equivalent of xp's fixbr fixboot and bootcfg /rebuild. Win9X had just fdisk /mbr. With Win 7 it's one command bootrec with whatever switch.

Comment: it's possible some of those include others like maybe fixboot includes fixmbr but anyhow.

Comment: For this act, I'm now unauthorized(in my home) to access the device. And, I cannot try the proposed solution. It is fixed now but still fragile.